# Rails nested resources url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I inherited this app (Rails 4.2.3, Ruby 2.2.2) and there are some nested resources defined as:

```
resources :meetings do
  resources :users, shallow: true
end
```

Given a meeting, I can access the users via /meetings/1#users, but not /meetings/1/users. Why is that?

**Update** with more infomation:

I do have this when run rake resources:

```
meeting_users GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/users(.:format)  users#index
POST                 /meetings/:meeting_id/users(.:format)  users#create
```

The error I got from access /meetings/1/users is from users controller:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

In users controller:

```
def index
   @users = User.where(meeting: @meeting)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json
   end
end
```

The error points to the `respond_to do |format|` line

Comment: What does it tell you when you try accessing `/meetings/1/users` ? Can you show your users_controller index action?

Comment: I don't even understand why you could access it *without* using an actual path. You sure something isn't being used on the front-end that uses SPA-style links?

Comment: Also, in terminal if you run the rake task `rake routes` what does it give you? (my feeling is that the route should be defined)

Answer (score 0):

With your given routes info, you should have a route like this: (`bundle exec rake routes`):

```
meeting_users GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/users(.:format)     users#index
```

So, you should be able to access `/meetings/1/users` which will be served by `users_controller`'s `index` action and will take you to the corresponding `index` view.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @K M Rakibul Islam's answer, you can access the link by prepending each resource's path name in front of the `_path` suffix, and passing in the meeting object, like so:

```
<%= link_to "View users for this meeting", meeting_users_path(@meeting) %>
```

You will have to have a single specific `@meeting` object defined in your controller such as `@meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])` or whatever you are looking up the meeting with.

Also, to note, that when using `shallow: true` on a resourceful route, it will only generate the nested routes for `[:index, :new, :create]` and not for `[:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]`. The latter would have to be accessed without the `meeting_` prefix.

```
# Since using shallow, these would need the meeting prefix
meeting_users    GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/users(.:format)     users#index
new_meeting_user GET    /meetings/:meeting_id/users/new(.:format) users#new
meeting_users    POST   /meetings/:meeting_id/users(.:format)     users#create

# These would not need the meeting prefix
edit_user        GET    /users/:id/edit                           users#edit
user             GET    /users/:id                                users#show
user             PATCH  /users/:id                                users#update
user             PUT    /users/:id                                users#update
user             DELETE /users/:id                                users#destroy
```